# For any nonzero $\mathbf{\vec{w}}\in\mathbb{C}^n$ there is a smallest $m$ such that $A^m \mathbf{\vec{w}}$ is a linear combination

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

While reading about finding eigenvectors in Hubbard & Hubbard's Vector Calculus I have found the following statement:

"For any nonzero $\mathbf{\vec{w}}\in\mathbb{C}^n$ there is a smallest $m$ such that $A^m \mathbf{\vec{w}}$ is a linear combination of $$\mathbf{\vec{w}}, A\mathbf{\vec{w}}, A^2 \mathbf{\vec{w}}, A^{m-1}\mathbf{\vec{w}}:$$ there exist numbers $a_0,\dots, a_{m-1}$ such that $$a_0\mathbf{\vec{w}}+a_1 A\mathbf{\vec{w}}+a_2 A^2 \mathbf{\vec{w}}+\dots+a_{m-1}A^{m-1}\mathbf{\vec{w}}+A^m \mathbf{\vec{w}}=\mathbf{\vec{0}}"$$

Why is this statement true?
I would be grateful if someone could explain it to me or point out a source for a proof of this statement. Thanks.

Comment: Think about how large a linearly independent set of $\mathbb{C}^n$ could be.

Comment: @angryavian there can be at most $n$ independent vectors, and since $\mathbf{\vec{w}}, A\mathbf{\vec{w}}, A^2 \mathbf{\vec{w}}, A^{m-1}\mathbf{\vec{w}}$ are already $n$ vectors in $\mathbb{C}^n$, either they are already linearly dependent, or $A^m$ in the collection $\mathbf{\vec{w}}, A\mathbf{\vec{w}}, A^2 \mathbf{\vec{w}}, A^{m-1}\mathbf{\vec{w}}, A^m$ is. Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since all the vectors $\mathbf{\vec w},A\mathbf{\vec w},A^2\mathbf{\vec w},\ldots$ belong to $\Bbb C^n$, which is finite-dimensional, there is a smallest $m\in\Bbb N$ such that the set $\{\mathbf{\vec w},A\mathbf{\vec w},A^2\mathbf{\vec w},\ldots,A^m\mathbf{\vec w}\}$ is linearly dependent. So, there are scalar $\alpha_0,\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n$, not all of which are $0$, such that $\alpha_0\mathbf{\vec w}+\alpha_1A\mathbf{\vec w}+\cdots\alpha_mA^m\mathbf{\vec w}=0$. And we cannot have $\alpha_m=0$, since then we would have $\alpha_0\mathbf{\vec w}+\alpha_1A\mathbf{\vec w}+\cdots\alpha_{m-1}A^{m-1}\mathbf{\vec w}=0$, but we chose $m$ as the smallest natural such that the set $\{\mathbf{\vec w},A\mathbf{\vec w},A^2\mathbf{\vec w},\ldots,A^m\mathbf{\vec w}\}$ is linearly dependent. So, $\alpha_m\ne0$, and we have$$A^m\mathbf{\vec w}=-\frac{\alpha_0}{\alpha_m}\mathbf{\vec w}-\frac{\alpha_1}{\alpha_m}\mathbf{\vec w}-\cdots-\frac{\alpha_{m-1}}{\alpha_m}\mathbf{\vec w}.$$